# I want to install EA Origin

Tags: software-installation

I recently just started using Ubuntu and Linux. I'm an amateur.

I used to have Windows and in it I had origin from EA and I want to play the games I had there, but I see that there is no straightforward way to install it for Linux.

I saw on some pages that I must have wine and playonlinux So I downloaded them. The problem is, when I click the file of origin to open it with wine,  it flashes like it wants to load and then nothing.

What exactly do I have to do to Install Origin?

Comment: Hi Nanz unfortunately there is no any other straight way to do this. It should be only through Wine. Make sure wine installed without any conflict or errors or reinstall both wine and origin. And about performance its very hard and buggy. Because the game has to run through wine.

Comment: Origin is not yet fully supported by WINE, and based on the amount of bugs, it doesn't look like it will be in the near future. Also, Origin is purely a launcher, so even if it WAS supported by WINE, you'd still have the issue of whether the *game* is supported by WINE. Related: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26175